# Were the first and third person singular forms of verb earlier the same?

Tags: conjugation

I've read Lord's Prayer in German (Vaterunser) recently and found an intersting thing.

Where the third person signular form of the verb is supposed to be used, we see the first one:

> Vater unser im Himmel, geheiligt **werde** dein Name.
>
> Dein Reich **komme**.
>
> Dein Wille **geschehe**, wie im Himmel, so auf Erden.

My question is, were these forms in the past the same? If yes, why have they changed (werde → wird, komme → kommt, geschehe → geschieht, and so on)?

**Update.** I'm not native English speaker, so the comparison with English version doesn't explain me, why it is so. But with Ansgar Esztermann's answer, I finally got it! Thanks.

Comment: These forms still exist nowadays and are called subjunctive (or Konjunktiv in German).

Comment: And what have we here (in Vaterunser)? Is it subjunctive?

Comment: In English you say *Praise be to the name of God.* as well, and not *The name of God  is praised.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like @Em1 said, this is the subjunctive form. Cf. the English version:

> Holy *be* Thy name
>
> Thy kingdom *come*
>
> Thy will *be* done

That is, this is not supposed to be statement of facts, but of wishes.